# Are there maven-plugins with licenses that prevent their use in open source projects?

Tags: licensing, maven

Are there maven-plugins that should not be used in opensource projects?

- Because their license restricts that
- Because they add code

...

In other words: Is it save to ignore the plugins when looking for license restrictions?

Update:
bmargulies's answer is what I feared but:

Q: Is there an actual plugin that I could not use in a non-open project distributed to customers ?

Comment: Are talking really about plugins to Maven or regular Jars available through Maven? And is this correct that you are talking about the Maven Central repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible to answer the question about the existence of a maven plugin, somewhere, in some repository. Not all Maven plugins are even on Maven central.

A maven plugin could, certainly, plop a lump of IP into your project with a license that is incompatible with your needs. And no protocol in Maven forces a plugin to announce this in any obvious way.

In the absolute worst case, some jerk could hide some proprietary content in a plugin and deposit it *in binary* in your output, and then later come around and claim that what you've built is a derived work and you owe, you owe.

At the end of the day, you're never *completely* safe in the land of open source unless you, well, *read the source*. If you are going to use a Maven plugin that is not from one of the mainstream sources, you would be well-advised to take a gander at its source even if you aren't worried about some sort of unpleasant IP implant.

There's a sort of trivial example in the form of the maven-archetype-plugin. It generates source code from templates licensed under the terms of the Apache License. Someone could claim that this makes the generated code into a derived work of the template, and subject to the terms of the AL. Or, worse, someone could push a template with some troublesome license, and nothing in the archetype plugin warns you when you select an archetype as to what the licensing is.

Comment: so it is possible. Do you know of any such plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

The archetype plugin creates sources from an apache-licensed template. from an extreme viewpoint, that is an examples.

Comment: but apache-licensed should not create a problem, right ?
I am looking for a known malicious plugin.